# How do I edit and save voxel size and the corresponding affine of a 3D volume in Nifti format in python?

Tags: python, image, medical, nifti, nibabel

I'm changing the voxel size of some 3D volumes. How do I edit the `pixdim` field and calculate the new `affine`?

I have some MR volumes which are anisotropic, the voxel sizes are, say, `0.5 x 0.5 x 3` mm. And I've some code to interpolate them into isotropic (like `0.5 x 0.5 x 0.5` mm voxel size) volumes.
The problem is when I need to save the file, I have to calculate the affine to map the now denser voxels in ijk space to reference xyz space. How do I do that?

First, my thought is to use the old affine and calculate the new affine.

For example, if volume V has a shape of `256 x 256 x 20` voxels with `0.5 x 0.5 x 3` voxel size and interpolated into volume U `256 x 256 x 120` voxels with `0.5 x 0.5 x 0.5` voxelsize.

The old affine will do `[255 255 19]OA = [X Y Z]` and the new affine should do `[255 255 119]NA = [X Y Z]` and we know `AX=B X=inverse(A)B`.

So the new affine should be `inverse([255 255 119])[X Y Z]`.
However, the inverse matrix only exists for a square matrix. There will be no such thing of `inverse([255 255 119])`.

And it seems there is no `set_voxel_size` function in python-nibabel matlab-nifti-toolbox and so. How does that a case?

How do I change the voxel size explicitly?

Answer (score 1):

I am facing a similar problem at the moment. To solve it, I create a nifti header from scratch with 0.5  mm isotropic voxels and the desired shape. You can use [`header.set_zooms()`](https://nipy.org/nibabel/nibabel_images.html#the-image-header) to set the voxel size in mm.

```py
import nibabel as nib
import numpy as np

hdr = nib.Nifti1Header()
hdr.set_data_shape((256, 256, 120))
hdr.set_zooms((0.5, 0.5, 0.5))  # set voxel size
hdr.set_xyzt_units(2)  # millimeters
dst_aff = hdr.get_best_affine()

src_aff = np.eye(4)
src_aff_inv = np.linalg.inv(src_aff)

transform = np.matmul(src_aff_inv, dst_aff)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer on how to change the size. But this way still discarded the affine that maps voxel coordinate back to scanner coordinate.